# Get all records that don't completely match on all fields from a table JOIN

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I've got a situation where I updated one table with some 3rd party utility, and I want to compare it to the original table and make sure it made the correct mount of updates and inserts.

So, I'd like to do something like this, but I don't quite know the syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS a RIGHT OUTER JOIN table2 AS b WHERE 
    <there is some difference between the row from a and the row from b,
    regardless of which column it's in>
```

How can I compare all the fields without having to explicitly write them all one by 1?

**EDIT:** I should also mention that I did the update in a *copy of the table*, so assume  is the original and  is the updated copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should use is a MINUS query

```
select field1, field2, field3, field4
  from table1
 except 
select field1, field2, field3, field4
  from table2
```

this returns all rows from table1 that whose data (field1, field2, field3, field4) can not be found on table2. Warining: it does not the other way around, so if you also need the data that is in table2 and not on table1, then you have to do a second query doing table2 MINUS table1.

Comment: Minus relational operator in TSQL is `EXCEPT` (same as standard SQL).

Comment: @onedaywhen Sorry, I come from Oracle developing :)